# ajax- pass dropdown option values as a list

Tags: ajax, jquery, drop-down-menu

i have a drop down list which allows multiple select like this:

```
<select id="myId" >
   <option value="1">Value 1</option>
   <option value="2">Value 2</option>
   <option value="3">Value 3</option>
   <option value="4">Value 4</option>
 </select>
```

now on change the option i need to make an ajax call (to my controller) which sends the value of selected options

```
  $("#myId").change(function(){
   var myId= $("#myId").val();
       $.ajax({
    url:"${createLink(controller:'clientTrip',action:'fillData')}",
    data: ({myId:myId}),  // i want myid to be sent as list 
    dataType: "html",

    success: function(data) {

    }
});
  });
```

i want to get value of myId as a list (list of selected option values) in my controller.. 
how can i do it? what changes i should make ?

Answer (score 0):

You should most likely use the [selected selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/). Something like the following should work

```
$("#myId").change(function(){
   var myIds = new Array();
   $("#myId option:selected").each(function(){
       myIDS.push($(this).val());
   })
       $.ajax({
            url:"${createLink(controller:'clientTrip',action:'fillData')}",
            data: ({myId:myIds}),  // i want myid to be sent as list 
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(data) {

            }
        });
  });
```